# Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Indicator Function

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

I need to solve this exercise from the book below.

$\textbf{Mathematical Statistics, Knight (2000)}$

$\textbf{Problem 6.17}$

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with frequency function

\begin{equation}
  f(x;\theta)=\begin{cases}
    \theta                 & \text{for $x=-1$}.\\
    (1- \theta)^2 \theta^x & \text{for $x=0,1,2,\ldots$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

(a) Find the Cramer-Rao lower bound for unbiased estimators based on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

(b) Show that the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ based on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is

$$\hat{\theta}_n = \frac{2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{(X_{i}=-1)} + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{2n + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$

and show that $\{\hat{\theta}_n\}$ is consistent for $\theta$.

(c) Show that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)\to_d N(0,\sigma^2(\theta))$ and find the value of $\sigma^2(\theta)$. Compare $\sigma^2(\theta)$ to the Cramer-Rao lower bound in part (a).

---

No clue on how to solve (a) or (c).

I started to solve (b) but I can't seem to arrive at the desired solution. I'm getting this:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= \prod_{i=1}^n (1-\theta)^2 \theta^{x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)} + I_{(X_{i}=-1)}} \\
\mathcal{L} &= (1-\theta)^{2 \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i \geq 0)}} \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)} + \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_{i}=-1)}} \\
\log \mathcal{L} &= 2 \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i \geq 0)} \log(1-\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)} \log \theta + \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i=-1)} \log \theta
\end{align}

$\textbf{FOC}$

\begin{align}
0 &= - \frac{2 \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i \geq 0)}}{1-\theta} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)}} \theta + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i=-1)}} \theta \\ \\
\hat{\theta}_n &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i=-1)} + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)}}{\sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i=-1)} + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n I_{(X_i \geq 0)} + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i I_{(X_i \geq 0)}}
\end{align}

which differs from the result I'm given...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that is provided suggests that for a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, we should define a random variable $K = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{x_i = -1}$; that is, $K$ counts the number of observations that equal to $-1$.  Then 
$$\begin{align*} \mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) &= \theta^K \prod_{j=1}^{n-K} (1-\theta)^2 \theta^{x_{[j]}} \\
&= \theta^K (1-\theta)^{2(n-K)} \theta^{\sum_{j=1}^{n-K} x_{[j]}} 
\end{align*}$$
where $x_{[j]}$ represents the $j^{\rm th}$ observation of $\boldsymbol x$ that is nonnegative.  But note that $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-K} x_{[j]} = K + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = K + n \bar x.$$  So we may write the log-likelihood as $$\ell (\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = 2(n-K) \log (1-\theta) + (2K + n\bar x) \log \theta. $$  Thus the log-likelihood is maximized at a critical point satisfying $$0 = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = -\frac{2(n-K)}{1 - \theta} + \frac{2K +n\bar x}{\theta},$$ or $$\hat \theta = \frac{2K + n \bar x}{n (2+\bar x)}.$$  This is equivalent to the stated solution (just written more compactly).

You may find that working with $K$ and avoiding the unnecessary use of additional indicator functions (you really only need one, namely $\mathbb 1_{x_i = -1}$) will reduce your chances of making errors.  Please feel free to attempt the other parts of the question.

---

If you find it difficult to follow the above solution, it is helpful to consider a numeric example.  Suppose you are given the sample $$\boldsymbol x = (-1, 0, 1, 3, -1, 5, -1).$$  Then $n = 7$, $K = 3$, and the sample total is $n \bar x = 6$.  We observe that $K + n\bar x = 3 + 6 = 9$, which is equal to the sum of nonnegative observations $\sum_{j=1}^{n-K} x_{[j]} = 0 + 1 + 3 + 5 = 9$.

The resulting likelihood function is $$\mathcal L (\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = \theta^3 (1-\theta)^{2(7-3)} \theta^{0+1+3+5} = \theta^{12} (1-\theta)^8.$$  This is maximized when $\hat \theta = 12/(8+12) = 3/5$.

Comment: Thanks! Your approach was great! Once I have that, how should I work with K to find the Fisher Information Matrix?

Comment: @Slakeon You've got the first derivative of the log-likelihood already.  Now calculate the second derivative, and compute its expectation.  The tricky part is to notice that $$K \mid \theta \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p = \theta),$$ because by definition $\Pr[X = -1 \mid \theta] = \theta$; thus $K \mid \theta$ which counts the number of such outcomes, is a binomial random variable and its expectation is $\operatorname{E}[K \mid \theta] = n\theta$.  What is $\operatorname{E}[n\bar X]$, the expected sample total?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
L(\theta) & = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta^{I_{x_i=-1}} (1-\theta)^{2 I_{x_i\ge 0} } \theta^{x_i I_{x_i\ge 0}}. \\[10pt]
\ell(\theta) = \log L(\theta) & = (\log\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n (I_{x_i=-1} + x_i I_{x_i \ge 0} ) + 2(\log(1-\theta)) \sum_{i=1}^n I_{x_i\ge0} \\[10pt]
\ell\,'(\theta) & = \frac 1 \theta \sum_{i=1}^n (I_{x_i=-1} + x_i I_{x_i \ge 0}) - \frac 2 {1-\theta} \sum_{i=1}^n I_{x_i\ge 0} = \frac A \theta -2\frac B {1-\theta} \\[10pt]
& = 0 \text{ if and only if } A(1-\theta) - 2B\theta = 0, \\[10pt]
& \qquad \text{and that holds precisely if } A = 2B\theta+A\theta = (A+2B)\theta, \text{ so} \\[10pt]
\theta & = \frac A {A+2B} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (I_{x_i=-1} + x_i I_{x_i \ge 0})}{\sum_{i=1}^n (I_{x_i=-1} + x_i I_{x_i \ge 0}) + 2\sum_{i=1}^n I_{x_i\ge 0}}.
\end{align}

Comment: How would you get to the desired result proceeding like this?

Comment: @Slakeon Recalling that we defined $K = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{x_i = -1}$, then you can see that the numerator is is simply $K + \sum_{j=1}^{n-K} x_{[j]} = K + K + n \bar x = 2K + n \bar x$, as shown in my answer.  The denominator simplifies in a similar fashion, noting that $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{x_i \ge 0} = n - K$.  This illustrates the power of a careful choice of convenient and concise notation.

Comment: @Slakeon : More tomorrow $\ldots\qquad$